How can a member of an enum be of the same type as the enum itself?
Internally enums seem to be a pair of arrays, one of strings for the names and the other usually of ints. When I select a specific enum member and pass it into a method (i.e. NflTeams.Raiders) I would expect the parameter type to be an int, or maybe a tuple of a string and int, but the member is actually of the same type as the enum itself (i.e. NflTeams). What's going on there? Is a copy of the enum being passed in? Could it be that an enum member is like the "instance" property of a singleton, which is of the same type as the singleton itself?
I've looked at the C# source code for the System.Enum type here:  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,36729210e317a805. I see a private class in there called ValuesAndNames that seems pretty central to how an enum works. I understand that it's a pair of arrays with member names and corresponding values, but I still can't figure out what exactly happens when I select a specific enum member.
I've also used ReSharper to look at the decompiled code for some of my enums. If I try to drill down into a specific member in my code (right click and go to definition) it won't let me go into the source code for the member.
I've also read microsoft learn documentation on enums like this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums

"Internally enums seem to be a pair of array" - No, they aren't. What you're describing is how CLR's Reflection API was designed - which is entirely disconnected from how enum types actually work in the CLR.

"What's going on there?" - enum types are types - not C-style #define constants that use existing types (invariably int).

Please read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/august/cutting-edge-all-about-enums

"enums seem to be a pair of arrays, one of strings for the names and the other usually of ints" where did you get that from? What made you think that would be the case? Also have you read ECMA-335 on how enums work? https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2101%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C308%2C0%5D The private class ValueAndNames you seem so concerned about is just a helper class for using reflection to get the names at runtime, the values as they stand in your code are just int constants.

@Dai Actually that is basically how they work. Although the enum itself is a type, the values are implemented as int constants, as if they were constant fields public const int First = 0; public const int Second = 1; More the point: in C# constants are compiled directly into the IL bytecode, so if you decompile it then you can't see tha name.

@Charlieface ILSpy can't, but other IL disassemblers work just fine with enum locals.

@Dai That's because they are reconstructing what they think you typed. The IL simply does not contain this information. Try var x = (MyEnum)1 and you'll see what I mean.

@Dai  The IL code in that learn article you posted is really helpful. It looks like each enum member is a static property of the same type as the enum. I can actually chain the members together if I write something like NflTeams.Raiders.Chargers.Broncos, etc., although that causes an error. That's interesting. I'll chew on that article for a bit and try to understand it better. Thanks!

@Charlieface I thought it was a pair of arrays partly because each enum value has a corresponding string name. So one array for the names, one for the int values. So names[0] goes with value[0], etc. But also because I saw that ValuesAndNames class. But it's beginning to click now, I think. There is no array of string names, those are literally just the names of properties on the enum which can be turned into an array of strings using reflection. I'll check out that ECMA article you posted. Thank you!


Could it be that an enum member is like the "instance" property of a
singleton, which is of the same type as the singleton itself?

More or less but it's a field.

Would someone please comment on what they found unhelpful about this?  Clearly, I could have gone into much more depth, but I expect this would directly address the OP's point of confusion.

Thanks! It helps me to think of it that way even it there's a little more nuance to it than that. And it lines up with what I see in the IL code. It's still hard for me to wrap my brain around how the enum can be both a collection and have a specific, single underlying value. I can see that each of those static members has one specific underlying value but it's also somehow a collection. I can even chain those members together like Color.Red.Blue.Green. I guess that might be all there is to know about it, that's what this C# type is/does. But it blows my mind a little bit, lol.

.class nested public sealed auto ansi Color extends [System.Runtime]System.Enum
{
.field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
.field public static literal valuetype Sandbox.EnumStuff/Color Red = int32(0) // 0x00000000
.field public static literal valuetype Sandbox.EnumStuff/Color Blue = int32(1) // 0x00000001
.field public static literal valuetype Sandbox.EnumStuff/Color Green = int32(2) // 0x00000002
}

this sounds more like a comment than a understandable and clear answer


Internally enums seem to be a pair of arrays, one of strings for the names and the other usually of ints.

This is not what enums are. This is not even how enums are implemented. This is just part of the runtime machinery that facilitates reflection for enums. It is unrelated to understanding what an enum is.

When I select a specific enum member and pass it into a method (i.e. NflTeams.Raiders) I would expect the parameter type to be an int, or maybe a tuple of a string and int, [...]

These expectations are unwarranted.

but the member is actually of the same type as the enum itself (i.e. NflTeams).

That is correct.

What's going on there?

Part of the confusion is due to the fact that many people refer to enum values as "enum members". The official Microsoft documentation also does that.
It is best to never call them "enum members", and instead call them "enum values" or "enum constants".
Technically, the term "members" is not wrong, but it requires that everyone participating in the discussion already understands that this meaning of "member" is not the exact same as the meaning of "member" in a struct: in both cases we think of it as a "member" because it is a participant in a greater whole, but in the case of enums, the participants are just constant definitions, they do not reserve any kind of storage as they do in a struct, they cannot be initialized or written to as they would in a struct.
An enum is a set of constants that collectively constitute a type.
When you declare the following:
enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Neutral
}

You are creating a new type called Gender. An instance of that type is a value which must be one of the three available constants: Gender.Male, Gender.Female, and Gender.Neutral. In other words, these three constants are values of type Gender, and they are the only valid values for type Gender.
That's how "a member of an enum [is] of the same type as the enum itself", and this is not any different from saying that 42 is of the same type as int itself. Yes, that's precisely it's type, by definition. That's how things work, and nothing would work otherwise.
To see it in a different way, ints could, in a purely hypothetical and purely conceptual way, be thought of as follows:
enum int
{
   -2147483648,
   -2147483647,
   -2147483646,
   ...
   -3
   -2
   -1
   0
   1
   2
   3
   ...
   2147483645,
   2147483646,
   2147483647
}

(...plus the ability to perform arithmetic with them, which is something that normally you cannot do with enum values.)
Under the hood, enum values are implemented in C# as ints, (just as in C and C++,) so it only takes a type-cast to convert between an enum value and its ordinal. However, that's not the only way to implement enum values. For example, Java takes a slightly less efficient but far more elegant and flexible approach, where enum values are not ints; instead, each value is a separate object instance. In this design, if you want to know which enum value corresponds to a certain ordinal you have to ask the enum type for it, and if you have an enum value at hand and you are curious about it's ordinal, you can invoke it's .ordinal() method to obtain it.

I am not going to downvote this because a lot of the answer is probably helpful. Still, I'd suggest clarifying a couple of aspects: [1] the part "plus the ability to perform arithmetic with them, which is something that normally you cannot do with enum values" is ambiguous with respect to the notion of "bitwise arithmetic", which is generally supported by enums; and, [2] there is a distinction between enum values and their underlying integer representations in that multiple enum values may be assigned to the same integer, which would seem to conflict with your enum int example.

@smartcaveman this question and answer is looking at enums at a very basic level, so I thought it is best not to complicate the discussion with [Flags].  Also, note that I wrote "normally" precisely in order to account for [Flags].  The ability to assign specific values to enum constants is also an advanced feature, so I opted to not complicate the discussion with this. In any case, I think that leaving something out for the sake of brevity and clarity is one thing, saying something in conflict with reality is another.
